# Get RMI socket in RMI function?

Tags: java, ssl, rmi

I have a custom RMIClientSocketFactory which override "createSocket" to create a special socket.

How can i get hold of this socket in my rmi remote interface implementation? (the one that extends UnicastRemoteObject and implements interface that extends Remote)

I know that this isn't standard, but i wish to get the ssl certificate used by rmi in a rmi function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You're in the server, and the socket created in your `RMIClientSocketFactory` is in the client. That part of the question doesn't make sense.

You can however get hold of the socket created at *your* end by your `RMIServerSocketFactory.` It's a little fiddly, as you have to arrange to register the accepted sockets in a `ThreadLocal`, but it's doable.

Comment: My setup is also a bit confusing to me, i have a server which is running a rmi client which connects to a rmi server. When i do socket.getSession().getPeerPrincipal() in my createSocket() of my RMIClientSocketFactory i do get the certificate of the rmi server, that is the one i need. But i suspect that your note on using ThreadLocal still applies to my case. I do have some experience with threadlocals so i'm going to give it a shot today, let's see if i can get it to work. Cheers for the idea!

Comment: I just gave it a shot, but i'm using a single RMISSLClientSocketFactory for all my LocateRegistry.getRegistry() calls. Mainly because my RMISSLClientSocketFactory constructor sets up keystore/trustore, this is now done once for all my calls. But this means that a ThreadLocal in my RMISSLClientSocketFactory is always the same one. Do you have maybe have another lead i can follow?

Comment: The lead to follow is this one. I've already answered all this. The `RMISSLClientSocketFactory` is at the other end of the network. It can therefore be of no use to you at the server whatsoever. You have to write yourself an `RMIServerSocketFactory` that behaves as I described. Tricky but eminently possible. Essentially you have to override `accept()`; create a server-mode `SSLSocket` from the plaintext `Socket` you accepted; enter it into a `ThreadLocal`; and lookup that `ThreadLocal` inside your remote method implementation.